# Call same button inside different callbacks

Tags: rust, fltk

I'm trying to make a basic software in Rust using the GUI Library FLTK. See my code at Pastebin. I created a button called input1 at line 18. I need to call this button inside two different callbacks. But the first callback get the button ownership. So I get an error at line 41, on creating the second callback.
How could I create this button and call it inside the different callbacks?

https://pastebin.com/LKdfeKA3?fbclid=IwAR30JmY37ZIkmSMBzcwj0YuoWMLaLsMQwDtKJUgLUP01A-lm9d28bXzk0OM

```
use std::{borrow::BorrowMut, rc::Rc, cell::RefCell, sync::{Arc, Mutex}};
 
use fltk::{*, app, button::{Button, LightButton}, frame::Frame, prelude::*, window::Window, enums::*,  text::{TextBuffer, TextDisplay}};
use fltk_calendar::calendar;
use fltk::button::CheckButton;
use chrono::prelude::*;
 
fn main() {
 
    let mut data_geracao_str = String::new();
    let mut data_geracao_inicio_str = String::new();
 
    let app = app::App::default();
    let mut wind = Window::new(20, 40, 800, 600, "Gerador de Arquivos Diários - Armarinhos Fernando");
 
 
    let mut _titulo1 = Frame::new(30, 33, 150, 10, "Data Inicial");
    let mut input1 =  input::Input::new(160,25,150,35,"");
    let mut but_cal1 = button::Button::new(320, 25, 80, 36, "Calendário");
 
    but_cal1.set_label_size(10);
    input1.deactivate();
    but_cal1.deactivate();
 
 
    but_cal1.set_callback(   move|_| {
        let cal = calendar::Calendar::default();
        let naive_date = cal.get_date();
        if let Some(naive_date) = naive_date {
            data_geracao_inicio_str.clear();
            data_geracao_inicio_str.push_str(naive_date.format("%Y-%m-%d").to_string().as_str());
            input1.set_value(data_geracao_inicio_str.as_str());
            data_geracao_inicio_str.push_str(" 00:00:00 +00:00");
 
            println!("{:?}",&data_geracao_inicio_str);
 
        }
    });
 
    let mut check_input =  CheckButton::new(415,25,250,40,"Data Inicio Diferente");
    check_input.set_callback( |check1|{
        if check1.is_checked(){
            input1.set_value("");
            //input1.set_value("");
            //&input1.activate();
            but_cal1.activate();
        }else{
            //&input1.set_value("");
            //&input1.deactivate();
            but_cal1.deactivate();
        }
    });
 
    let mut _titulo2 = Frame::new(30, 95, 150, 10, "Data Final");
    let mut input2 =  input::Input::new(160,85,150,35,"");
    let mut but_cal2 = button::Button::new(320, 85, 80, 36, "Calendário");
    but_cal2.set_label_size(10);   
 
    let mut btn_pix = button::Button::new(30, 200, 110, 36, "PIX"); 
    let mut btn_vendas = button::Button::new(150, 200, 110, 36, "Vendas"); 
    let mut btn_previsao = button::Button::new(270, 200, 110, 36, "Previsão"); 
    let mut btn_recebimento = button::Button::new(390, 200, 110, 36, "Recebimento"); 
    let mut btn_ajustes = button::Button::new(510, 200, 110, 36, "Ajustes");  
 
    but_cal2.set_callback(move |_| {
        let cal = calendar::Calendar::default();
        let naive_date = cal.get_date();
        if let Some(naive_date) = naive_date {
            data_geracao_str.clear();
            data_geracao_str.push_str(naive_date.format("%Y-%m-%d").to_string().as_str());
            input2.set_value(data_geracao_str.as_str());
            data_geracao_str.push_str(" 00:00:00 +00:00");
 
            println!("{:?}",data_geracao_str);
 
        }
    });    
 
    wind.end();
    wind.show();
    app.run().unwrap();
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `.clone()` the `Button` to get a second handle to the same button, which you can hand off to the first callback without losing it in the second.

```rust
{
    let input1 = input1.clone();
    but_cal1.set_callback(move |_| {
        ...
        input1.set_value(data_geracao_inicio_str.as_str());
    });
}

// now you can still use input1 here
```

This is a common pattern in Rust libraries; whenever you have a value that acts as a handle to some entity that can be interacted with externally (the button in the window), rather than *only* being used by its owner, it often implements the [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) trait in this way. Unfortunately, they don't always document this pattern clearly; `fltk` only mentions it in passing [in its FAQ](https://github.com/fltk-rs/fltk-rs/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-memory-safe-is-fltk-rs). You should keep an eye out for when `Clone` is available and see if it does what you want.

Comment: It's new for me. I thinked that clone() would create other Button object in memory. I didn't know that it would create a handler to same button.
But your tip really worked. Thanks!

Comment: @PauloLuvisoto Well, it _is_ a new instance/value of the `Button` type. But that doesn't necessarily mean it is completely independent of the original.